# Is this a correct sentence: "I had a lot of troubles when I was young"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, singular-vs-plural, plural-forms, word-form

When I talk about the difficulties I experienced when I was young, can I say "I had a lot of troubles when I was young"? Or should I use the singular version after the word "have"? I think I am not very used to hearing "troubles" instead of "trouble" after "have". But here I am talking about different kinds of things that worried me and distressed me when I was young, so I think the sentence I provided is probably correct.

Comment: You are right. The two versions imply different things and in your context the plural is the better choice.

Comment: If you replaced **a lot of** with **many**, you would probably not have an issue. *I had **many** troubles when I was young.*